How to highlight a unique value from several cells
I have a list of cells with data inside, separated by a ,
I would like to extract all the value that are common to each cells.
It works, I stole it from internet, I don't understand it but it just works
I'm not really good in excel so don't ask to complexes questions and don't use Macro.
=LET(x; TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;C2:C3); ", "));y;UNIQUE(x);z;UNIQUE(x;;1); TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;IF(ISERROR(MATCH(y;z;0));y; "")))
My issue is that it only works for 2 cells.
If I test 3 or more, it will keep all value that appear several time, but I need to keep value that appeared in every single cell, not just 3 out of 4.

What's the point of including a screenshot, if you black it out for 90%? If it's senstive, try giving us some mock up data, preferably in a Table Markdown format

You can try this formula replace A10:A13 with the actual range
=LET( rng,A10:A13, col,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,rng),",",,TRUE,TRUE)), TOCOL(IF(BYROW(UNIQUE(col),LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=col))))=ROWS(rng),UNIQUE(col),1/0),3))
To arrange the result in one cell separated by comma use TEXTJOIN:
=LET( rng,A10:A13, col,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,rng),",",,TRUE,TRUE)), TEXTJOIN(",",,TOCOL(IF(BYROW(UNIQUE(col),LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=col))))=ROWS(rng),UNIQUE(col),1/0),3))) 


I think you got it. Thank you very much. I will just modify it to merge it into one single cell rather than 10 rows. But THX

@boivin12 added the merge formula to the answer.

I'll break down the formula for you, hope that gives you some insight in what you're actually doing:
LET is a formula that lets you define names, use those names later on, for eassier/faster calculations.  Any cells, arrays, rows, columns, whatever are formed within the formula, stay within the formula (important later), until one output is made (a cell, an array, ...).
Your first name is x, and x defines the forumla behind it, which I'll break down next:
In the center, ther's TEXTJOIN, which joins (merges) text with a certain delimeter (which is ", " in your case), so all your cells are added together in one cell, with ", ".
Around the TEXTJOIN is a TEXTSPLIT, which splits the entire 'cell' you just formed, into an row of cells, again using a delimter, which is ", " again, now this delimeter determines where your text is split; So anytime it encounters ", " it will eject a new cell into the row;
Next up is TRANSPOSE, this just turns/pivots a row into a column and vice versa. (so TEXTJOIN made a row, which is now turned into a column.)
All of the above is now x, within the LET formula.

Next up are y and z, they use UNIQUE, basically filtering out duplicate data;

Lastly, there's the calculation part, with in the center a MATCH function, which basically searches for a value inside of a matrix, and returns it position (either row or column).
Around that MATCH is a IFERROR function, which checks for errors, surrounded by an IF function, which then returns a value depending on if an error was found or not, when it finds one, y is returned, which is explained above. If no error is found, it returns a 'blank' cell ("").
This whole thing is again wrapped with a TEKSTJOIN, which I already mentioned above.

Now, I'm not sure how the IF(IFERROR()) part is supposed to work, the formula didn't work for me.
But when I replaced IFERROR() with ISNUMBER(), it worked for me: outputted one cell with all non-duplicate strings combined.

See image: green cells where duplicate, so those are skipped, the other ones are combined into one (the last one).

Thanks for reading my TED talk.

This has actually helped me. But my main problem remains. If it detects at least one value twice, it won't take into account the fact that my list of unique values (which don't appear in every single cells) gets shorter and shorter as I add cells to check. So I need to have either a list of all the values that appear every time, or a list of all the values that don't appear in at least one cell.

@Boivin12 help me understan, words don't do it anymore at this point of the day, one cell has a,b,c and another has b, x, y, what do you want to happen? output a, b, c, x, y?

Your formula defines three variables (that's what the Let() worksheet function is used for), and does some calculations on those variables.
First I advise you to check the meaning of those variables, and try to figure out how they are used in the final TextJoin() worksheet function.
As an aid, you might use formula auditing, which you can find here:

